# Are there any disadvantages to eating corpses?

Tags: fallout-4

The Cannibalism perk allows me to consume the flesh of dead people, and eventually Ghouls and Supermutants too.

One of the first new meals I've decided to take after mastering Cannibalism, was a Feral Ghoul who clearly didn't understand his place in the Food Chain. Unfortunately, Nick Valentine didn't exactly approve of my new-found tastes.

Since I don't like it when people judge me by my tastes, I've decided to wander alone with Dogmeat. He's a good boy, by the way. Never judges me for anything I do. Still loves me, even if I unload entire magazines full of lead or plasma into his cranium.

In any case, I've started enjoying the culinary delights of Cannibalism. Until recently, that is. Now, I'm plagued with doubt. What if I eat *too much*? Am I going to end up with human meat addiction? Will I suffer from Ghoulification as a result of eating just one more Supermutant for the road? Are people going to fear me or treat me with disdain if rumors about my preferences for Ghoul meat start circulating?

Aside from boring companions disliking cannibals, what disadvantage does my new diet entail?

Comment: Its worth noting that not ALL companions are as dull

Comment: Being a fellow foodie, I can tell you *most*, but not all NPCs will turn hostile. When that happens, you know what you need to do...

Comment: Tastes aweful, trust me. ;)
I'm sure most companions except DogMeat and Strong will either dislike or hate the action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you plan on walking around in power armor you might have a problem since you can't eat people while in power armor. So you would have to exit the power armor to eat and then reenter which can get very tedious.

As for companions, you can tell them to walk away so that you may enjoy your meal in secret and then go fetch them when you're done. In addition to dogmeat not caring that you are a cannibal you can also bring Hancock who also neutral, or even better bring Strong. Strong actually LIKES that you eat corpses:)

Answer (score 4):

If you play in survival mode in fallout 4, and choose to eat a corpse, you will get "dark cravings" and normal food will no longer satisfy you, you will have to eat more corpses in order to alleviate your hunger.

Comment: It should be noted that Dark Craving also means you no longer heal from sleeping or consuming regular food.

Comment: Dark Craving is an addiction and can be removed by a doctor or Addictol.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that with the intimidation perk you can threaten a enemy into doing as you command and thus simply bring them along with you as an extra no weight meal to keep handy when you want.

Comment: Nice info, but doesn't actually seem to answer the question. If the questionw would be about the _advantages_, sure, but it's the opposite question.